# Error getting RSS as XML file from database

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rss

**Error when you get rss from Databases 
I want to get the data in xml file.**

I want to bring data from mysql to display in rss xml file.
I think the problem in xml codes is in this file:
Note that 000 is changing index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>000</title>
<link>http://000.com/</link>
<description>000</description>
<language>ar-ye</language>
<copyright>000</copyright>
<pubpubDate>Mon, 09 Mar 2015 16:22:58 PDT</pubpubDate>
<lastBuildpubDate>Mon, 09 Mar 2015 16:22:58 PDT</lastBuildpubDate>
<category>000</category>
<generator>In house</generator>
<docs>000</docs>
<?php
    $url = "http://000.com";
?>
<!-- Start While with 80 news items -->
<?php
<?php
  ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8'); 
$host = '000';
$username= '000';
$password='000';
$database = '000';

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database) or die("Database connection failer");
$sSQL= 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8'; 

mysqli_query($con,$sSQL) 
or die ('Can\'t charset in DataBase'); 
    $query = mysql_query("SEELCT `id,text,date` FROM `$htmlpages` WHERE `id`='5' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 80");
    while($results = mysql_fetch_array())
    {
?>
    <item>
        <id><!-- News ID --></id>
        <proirity><!-- 1=Yes   0=No --></proirity> <!-- Show in the Main Home Box or NOT -->
        <title><!-- News Title --></title>
        <content><!-- News Details - Full Text --></content>
        <image><?=$url?>/<!-- News Image - Directory and Image file name --></image>
        <image_thumb><?=$url?>/<!-- News Image - Directory and Thumb file name --></image_thumb>
        <image_description><!-- Image Description --></image_description>
        <category><!-- News Category Name --></category>
        <link><!-- News URL --></link>
        <pubDate><!-- News Date --></pubDate>
        <author><!-- News Author Name --></author>
    </item>
<?php
    }
?>
<!-- End -->

</channel>
</rss>
```

I get the following error:

> This page contains the following errors:
>        error on line 40 at column 18: xmlParsePI : no target name
>        Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
>        Almasdar Online http://000.com/ Latest News provided by 000.com ar-ye
>
> Copyright 2015, 000 Inc. Mon, 09 Mar 2015 16:22:58 PDT Mon, 09 Mar 2015
>        16:22:58  PDT Index - 000 In house http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/tech/rss/

Please help soon thank you.